# dynamic output module reference - Terraform

Tags: terraform

I don't know if it is possible but I would like to take outputs from different modules as needed:

```
locals {
  node_proyect = 
   [
      ["node_1", "project_A"],
      ["node_2", "project_B"],
      ...
      ["node_N", "project_N"],
   ]
}
```

Working modules:

```
module "node_1" {
  ...
}

[...]   

module "node_N" {
  ...
}
```

trying to do:

```
module "outputs_sample" {
  for_each = {for i,v in local.node_proyect: i=>v}
  ...
  node_name = module.node_[each.value[0]].node_name
  proyect_name = each.value[1]
  ...
}
```

What I want:

```
node_name --> module.node_node_1.node_name --> "string with the name with which the node has been created"
project_name --> "project_A"
```

Next for_each:

```
node_name --> module.node_node_2.node_name --> "string with the name with which the node has been created"
project_name --> "project_B"
```

But I get:

```
 Error: Reference to undeclared module
│ 
│   on ....tf line ..., in module "outputs_sample":
│ 1073:   node_name                            = module.node_[each.value[0]].node_name
│ 
│ No module call named "module.node_" is declared in module.....
```

**The output of the modules exists and works perfectly**, so if I do: `module.node_node_1.node_name` works.

I don't know how to make Terraform to interpret it like this, instead of literally as the error says: `module.node_[each.value[0]].node_name`

Comment: There are a few different problems here, but the first obstacle is that you are referencing outputs from undeclared modules. You need to declare those modules to have access to the outputs with normal usage in a config.

Comment: hey, hi @MattSchuchard , the output of the modules works perfectly if I do it "normally" like:

`module.node_node_1.node_name`

I don't know how to make it interpret it like this instead of `module.node_[each.value[0]].node_name`, maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Ok that is very relevant to the question, but omitted from the question, so you should probably add it to the question to avoid the ambiguity problem.

Comment: hey @MattSchuchard, sorry for not being very descriptive. I have tried to add more info

Answer (score 2):

Given that you stated the modules are declared in the same config directory despite being absent from the config provided in the question, we can first fix the type and structure of the `local` variable:

```
locals {
  node_proyect = {
    "1" = "proyect_A",
    "2" = "proyect_B"
  }
}
```

Now we can use this for module iteration and fix the value accessors and string interpolation, and remove the unnecessary list constructor also causing issues:

```
module "outputs_sample" {
  source   = "./module"
  for_each = local.node_proyect
  ...
  node_name    = "module.node_${each.key}.node_name"
  proyect_name = each.value
  ...
}
```

But this will still causes issues due to a violation of the Terraform DSL. You need to restructure your module declarations (still absent from question so need to be hypothetical here):

```
module "node" {
  ...
  for_each = local.node_proyect
  ...
}
```

and then the outputs can be accessed normally from the resulting map of objects:

```
module "outputs_sample" {
  source   = "./module"
  for_each = local.node_proyect
  ...
  node_name    = module.node[each.key].node_name
  proyect_name = each.value
  ...
}
```

After all of these fixes to your config you will achieve your goal.

Comment: Using this I still can't get TF to interpret the modified module output:
`node_name` --> `module.node_node_1.node_name` --> `"module.node_node_1.node_name"` instead of `"string with the name with which the node has been created"`

Comment: @naeroy You changed the question substantially, so I have to update the answer now. Please do not substantitally change the question again.

Comment: sorry, I was trying to give more info so that you can understand what I am trying to achieve.